# Image not loading from cache in yii

Tags: image, caching, yii, apc

I have migrate my yii application to my localhost (xampp) from server, then the images are not loading  in localhost but in server its working, 
I am using APC extension and have cache policy.

The images suppose to load from the cache but its not loading.

I have reset the asset and cache folders but still it has the problem.

Should i need to do anything when migrating the application?

Comment: APC cache is opcode cacher and I think its not related to images. Can you show some screens of Network tab in browser dev tools?